# Need to create photo slider in website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slider, slideshow

I want to introduce my entertainment venues in the city, in addition to any place I want to put a description put a few photos. I like the slide show of the photos could look something like this site: http://www.lenzor.com/

Click on a photo to this site when I open my photos and it will have 'previous' and 'next' buttons, I when I click the photo recreational sites desired lead couple'll see.

Comment: your question is too broad, you should ask for your specific problem with your work what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this tutorials will help you to build your photo gallery. 
Visit once
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/50-excellent-image-galleries-you-can-use-today--net-4063